# jsviews/jsrender Converter not working on {{:...}} tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsrender, jsviews

I am attempting to use a converter to modify a string in a jsrender template, but I can't seem to get the converter to work on a tag.
Using the example on [JsRender API documentation Using converters](https://www.jsviews.com/#converters@simple) for example, I have:

```
<script>
    $.views.converters("upper", function(val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
</script>
```

Then in my HTML I have `{{upper:Name}}` which throws an error in the console: **TypeError: val is undefined**, and the template does not render at all.

However, if I apply the converter directly to a string like `{{upper:"This should be uppercase"}}` it outputs the string in uppercase as expected.

The `{{:Name}}` tag works fine by itself, so why isn't the converter working with it?

In case it is relevant, this is an ASP.NET-MVC project and the JSON data rendered by the template is coming from a `$.post('@Url.Action(..,..)')...` response. It's working perfectly until I attempt to apply the converter to the tag. Are converters not usable in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Name` property is undefined in some case.

If you have a Name that is undefined, then `{{:Name}}` will render as the empty string, `""` - but `{{upper:Name}}` will throw an error since `undefined.toUpperCase()` will fail.

You can investigate by breaking on thrown errors, (or by putting a break point or `debugger` statement in the converter) and seeing where your undefined `Name` is coming from.

You can also prevent the error getting thrown - and instead get error information rendered out - by any of the following techniques

- write `{{upper:Name onerror=true}}` or `{{upper:Name onerror='bad'}}` (see https://www.jsviews.com/#onerror)
- write

  `$.views.converters("upper", function(val) {
    return val === undefined ? 'undefined' : val.toUpperCase();
  });`
- write `$.views.settings.debugMode(true);`

and see what output you get, to investigate further about where your undefined `Name` is occuring.

Comment: Thanks @BorisMoore I'm not sure what was wrong because I started up the project today and tried {{upper:Name onerror=true}} then everything started working, even after removing the onerror=true. But I'm sure the debugging info will help next time I come across a problem :)